# Can you increase replication on an existing Apache Geode region?

Tags: redundancy, geode, gfsh

The documentation shows that it is [easy to create a new region with redundancy](https://geode.apache.org/docs/guide/16/developing/partitioned_regions/set_pr_redundancy.html).

However, the [alter region](https://geode.apache.org/docs/guide/111/tools_modules/gfsh/command-pages/alter.html#topic_E74ED23CB60342538B2175C326E7D758) command doesn't show any way to modify the redundancy on a region you're already using. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you correctly stated, there's no option exposed through the `alter region` command to change the number of redundant copies.

A simple workaround, however, would be to [export](https://geode.apache.org/docs/guide/113/tools_modules/gfsh/command-pages/export.html#topic_263B70069BFC4A7185F86B3272011734) the region data, [destroy](https://geode.apache.org/docs/guide/113/tools_modules/gfsh/command-pages/destroy.html#topic_BEDACECF4599407794ACBC0E56B30F65) the region, [re-create](https://geode.apache.org/docs/guide/113/tools_modules/gfsh/command-pages/create.html#topic_54B0985FEC5241CA9D26B0CE0A5EA863) it using the new number of redundant copies, and [import](https://geode.apache.org/docs/guide/113/tools_modules/gfsh/command-pages/import.html#topic_jw2_2ld_2l) the data into the newly created region from scratch.

Comment: Hmmm this will work simply, but not for live regions. I think this would require you to do dual writing or some kind of workaround to stay available while updating to new replication settings?

Comment: I found this extra confusing because there are specific commands to `rebalance` and `restore redundancy`. Offhand it seems like an increase to a replication settings and one of these commands should work.

Comment: Yes, this will imply some downtime, that's for sure. Regarding `rebalance` and `restore redundancy` commands, they are used to achieve other purposes, not to change the actual region configuration.